# How do I script Google Drive to unshare all subfolders and files given a folder ID?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Google Drive has a problem: if you unshare a top level folder everything in the folder is still shared...I'm not sure how such a large bug could survive but it does...details here:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/p3LZQnRNB24

I don't want to manually go through and unshare everything manually, so I'm thinking I could create a script that I could just plug in the folder ID into and have it do all the work.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

this unshares someone from every folder and file in your drive.

```
// create a Google Document
// Tools / Script Editor
// paste this in
// update line 13 and save
// hit play to run. you may have to run several times as the script will die after 5 or 6 minutes.

function findSharedFolders() {
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app
  // https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227771/how-do-i-script-google-drive-to-unshare-all-subfolders-and-files-given-a-folder
  // https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/p3LZQnRNB24

  var email = "unwanted-address@gmail.com"; // <<<<< INSERT THE UNDESIRED EMAIL ADDRESS HERE

  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.appendParagraph(email).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders("'"+email+"' in writers");  while (folders.hasNext()) unshare_(folders.next(), body, email);
  var files   = DriveApp.searchFiles(  "'"+email+"' in writers");  while (  files.hasNext()) unshare_(  files.next(), body, email);
}

function unshare_(file, body, email) {
// Logger.log(file.getName());
   var para = body.appendParagraph(file.getName());
   try { file.removeEditor(email); }
   catch (e) { para.setLinkUrl(file.getUrl()); para.appendText(" (" + e + ")"); }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't unshare folders within folders. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The code example posted above simply copy pasting and running after adding an email address spit out an error.

### The error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEZBA.png

### The code suggested above for clarity.

> // create a Google Document // Tools / Script Editor // paste this in
>   // update line 13 and save // hit play to run. you may have to run
>   several times as the script will die after 5 or 6 minutes.
>
> function findSharedFolders() {   //
>   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app
>   // https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters   //
>   [How do I script Google Drive to unshare all subfolders and files given a folder ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227771/how-do-i-script-google-drive-to-unshare-all-subfolders-and-files-given-a-folder)
>   // https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/p3LZQnRNB24
>
> var email = "unwanted-address@gmail.com"; // <<<<< INSERT THE
>   UNDESIRED EMAIL ADDRESS HERE
>
> var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
>   body.appendParagraph(email).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
>   var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders("'"+email+"' in writers");  while
>   (folders.hasNext()) unshare_(folders.next(), body, email);   var files
>   = DriveApp.searchFiles(  "'"+email+"' in writers");  while (  files.hasNext()) unshare_(  files.next(), body, email); }
>
> function unshare_(file, body, email) { // Logger.log(file.getName()); 
>   var para = body.appendParagraph(file.getName());    try {
>   file.removeEditor(email); }    catch (e) {
>   para.setLinkUrl(file.getUrl()); para.appendText(" (" + e + ")"); } }

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works well but it is supposed to be run in a google doc (which it uses for logging out the information).

If you want to use it right from the script editor, just use the above code without the log stuff:

```js
// create a Google Document
// Tools / Script Editor
// paste this in
// update line 13 and save
// hit play to run. you may have to run several times as the script will die after 5 or 6 minutes.

function findSharedFolders() {
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app
  // https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227771/how-do-i-script-google-drive-to-unshare-all-subfolders-and-files-given-a-folder
  // https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/p3LZQnRNB24

  var email = "unwanted-address@gmail.com"; // <<<<< INSERT THE UNDESIRED EMAIL ADDRESS HERE

  var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders("'"+email+"' in writers");  while (folders.hasNext()) unshare_(folders.next(), email);
  var files   = DriveApp.searchFiles(  "'"+email+"' in writers");  while (  files.hasNext()) unshare_(  files.next(), email);
}

function unshare_(file, email) {
// Logger.log(file.getName());
   try { file.removeEditor(email); }
   catch (e) {  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this script https://github.com/HR/google-drive-unshare to completely unshare files and folders or a specific folder (with its ID) with someone and transfer ownership of them (copy all files and folders owned by them while unsharing them)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.