# Google Drive Link Unshare

Tags: google-drive-api

Every single document, file and folder is shared via link sharing in my Google Drive. Is there a way, or a script, to unshare every file inside every folder by turning link sharing off? Thanks in advance.
OP

Answer (score 0):

You can try this google app script code below, since there is no link that can turn off sharing globally:

```
// create a Google Document
// Tools / Script Editor
// paste this in
// update line 13 and save
// hit play to run. you may have to run several times as the script will die after 5 or 6 minutes.

    function findSharedFolders() {
      // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app
      // https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters
      // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227771/how-do-i-script-google-drive-to-unshare-all-subfolders-and-files-given-a-folder
      // https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/p3LZQnRNB24

      var email = "unwanted-address@gmail.com"; // <<<<< INSERT THE UNDESIRED EMAIL ADDRESS HERE

      var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
      body.appendParagraph(email).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
      var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders("'"+email+"' in writers");  while (folders.hasNext()) unshare_(folders.next(), body, email);
      var files   = DriveApp.searchFiles(  "'"+email+"' in writers");  while (  files.hasNext()) unshare_(  files.next(), body, email);
    }

    function unshare_(file, body, email) {
    // Logger.log(file.getName());
       var para = body.appendParagraph(file.getName());
       try { file.removeEditor(email); }
       catch (e) { para.setLinkUrl(file.getUrl()); para.appendText(" (" + e + ")"); }
    }
```

Source: [How do I script Google Drive to unshare all subfolders and files given a folder ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227771/how-do-i-script-google-drive-to-unshare-all-subfolders-and-files-given-a-folder)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is similar to what I am looking for, however I need to disable link sharing privilages, not individual sharing. Is there a way to accomplish this? Thanks. OP

Comment: @OctopusProteins: did you find a solution? I have in the same situation like you.